# Is there a way to SetVisibleSignature with the same field name?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, x509certificate, signature

I have the following code, which is inside a function to sign PDF files multiple times:

```
    PdfStamper stamper = null;
    stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, fout, '\0', null, true);
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
    appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(20, 10, 170, 60), 1, ourCompany);
```

I would like to successfully add a second signature from the same company without getting the error "The field ourCompany already exists".

Is there a way to set a new visible signature with the same field name, when I sign the PDF file for the second time? Or is there another way to achieve this? I'm using iTextSharp 5.5.11.

Comment: Do you want to replace the signature in the old field?

Comment: @mkl No, I would like to add a second signature from the same company.

Comment: @mkl Thank you, I just edited the question and now it's more clear, I think.

Comment: The actual signature is the value of the signature field. You don't want to replace the original signature. Thus, you need to use a field with a different name. So, either set `ourCompany` to a different value, I.e. explicitly use a different field name, or use `null` all the times, so itext chooses a new one.

Comment: @mkl Thank you. I've been learning from you since I joined StackOverflow.